# if statement with constant value

Tags: python, if-statement, arguments

Why only ***if*** statement is executed & not ***else*** statement if we write an ***if-else*** with ***if*** having constant value. For example this code in python

```
x=5
if 5:
 print("hello 5")
else:
 print("bye")
```

Also the point to be noted is that in second line even if I replace 5 with 500 or any number, if statement will be only executed.Can anyone please explain.

Comment: `if x == 5:` is what you want.

Comment: have you tried `if 0:`?

Comment: Why it always choosing if condition & not else condition

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. You have to write `if x == 5:` then it should work as expected. The syntax `if 5:` always evaluates to `True` (as '5' is a non-zero number), and therefore only the first part is executed...

Comment: @Alex that I know, I want to know the reason behind this behavior in the condition I witnessed

Comment: @Loocid I have tried that there it is fine, why it's working like this in such condition

Comment: @appleapple, No I have not

Comment: @BrijeshRoy *Any* value unequal to 0 compares to true. Quite common semantics among programming languages, not all support them, though (e. g. in Java, you have to compare explicitly against 0).

Comment: Similar with strings: Empty string and None evaluate to false, any other to true in boolean contexts.

Comment: @Aconcagua Well, not entirely true. `[]`,`{}`,`()`,`''`,`set()`,`None` are all falsey as I'm sure you know. Basically it's whatever is defined in an objects `__bool__` method, normally either having a 0 value or a 0 length is said to be `False`.

Comment: @FHTMitchell I wasn't talking about these... But yes, you are right!

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply some condition to execute the if-else statement such as (if x==5) or (if x==500). In this case, if the condition is justified then it will follow if statement else it will follow else statement. In your scenario, there is no condition to check with a constant number so it will be automatically converted to true.

Answer (score 0):

Python treats all integers greater than 0 as true. Mostly, you'd use this just as a binary choice, checking if an integer is 1. In this case 5 is being found to be true, which means else is not called, as the if was activated.

```
if 0:
    print("Hello")
```

will not print hello because 0 is false.

Comment: Any value **unequal** to 0!

Answer (score 0):

if-else requires a boolean response. Any number(**positive/negative**) other than 0 implies **True**.

Try:

```
if 5:
   print("hello 5")
else:
   print("bye")

output: hello 5
```

## #

```
if 0:
   print("hello 5")
else:
   print("bye")

output: bye
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an additional reason. It used to be the case that python, like c, had no `bool` type. So instead of saying

```
boolean = False  # or True
```

you would say

```
boolean = 0  # or 1 or any other int
```

Python later added the `bool` type with `True` and `False` constants, but they are really just wrappers of the ints `1` and `0` (infact `bool` is a subclass of `int`). This can be seen by

```
print(True + True)
print(False * 123)
print(True == 1)
print(False == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of if-else as a fork. 
You go either this way (statements with the if) or that way (statements with else). The decision which way to turn is done by the condition-expression following the keyword `if`.

If the condition-expression evaluates to

- any *non-zero* value the if-branch will be taken
- *zero* the else-branch will be taken